# Prove that M is a submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, proof-verification, complex-numbers

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a complex polynomial $f=\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^3a_iz^i$ without double zeroes. Consider for $l=2$ the set $M=\lbrace (z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^2: w^l-f(z)=0 \rbrace$. Prove that $M$ is a 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^2\cong \mathbb{R}^4$.

---

**My solution:**

We have consider a function $g:\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined by $g(z,w)=w^2-f(z) \Rightarrow M=g^{-1}(0)$, then the jacobian matrix is $Dg(z,w)=\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial z} & \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial w}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-f'(z) & 2w
\end{pmatrix}$. We have prove that this matrix have rank 1 in the points from $M$ such that $w^2-f(z)=0$, where $g:\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a function defined by $g(z,w)=w^2-f(z)$.

In effect, if $w\neq 0$ is clear that the rank of the matrix is 1. On the other hand, if $w=0$ the rank of the matrix is 0 only if $f'(z)=0$, but how $w^2-f(z)=0 \Rightarrow f(z)=0$, ie **we have that $z$ is a double zero of the complex polynomial $f$ since it annuls him and his derivative**, but for hypothesis of the problem this polynomial doesn't have double zeroes, therefore the rank of the matrix is 1. Therefore, $M$ is a complex submanifold 1-dimentional and hence a real submanifold 2-dimentional.

My doubt is what I highlighted in black. Why is this true?

Sorry if my english is bad, 
best regards.

Comment: This problem is identical to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572702/prove-that-is-a-sub-manifold-of-mathbbc2-cong-mathbbr4?rq=1. Where did you find this problem?

Comment: From the book ''Global Analysis - Ilka Agrícola & Thomas Friedrich''. But that link does not answer my question.

Comment: What are you unsure about? If $(z,0) \in M$, then $f(z) = 0$ by definition of $M$. But then $f'(z) \neq 0$ since $f$ has only simple zeros, and thus $Dg$ has rank $1$ on all of $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct (including the claim that you doubt).

If $f(r) = f'(r) = 0$, then $f$ has a double root at $r$: by the fundamental theorem of algebra, we can write $f = \prod_{i \in [3]} (z-r_i)$ and $f' = \sum_{i=1}^3 \prod_{j \in [3]\backslash i}(z-r_j)$ by product rule (here the notation $[n] = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$). If $f = 0$ then $f = r_i$ for some $i$, and yet if $f'(r_i) = 0$ then since $\prod_{j \in [3]\backslash k}(z - r_j) = 0$ for any $k \neq i$ (since $i \in [3] \backslash k)$, it follows that $\prod_{j \in [3] \backslash i}(z-r_j) = 0$, that is, one of the $r_j$'s, with $j \neq i$, is equal to $r_i$, so that $r_i$ is a double root.

I wrote the proof in a way that generalizes the result for higher degree polynomials (just replace every instance of 3 with $n$).